# PDFBox can't read some arabic glyphs??

Tags: java

I use PDFBox library to read pdf files in arabic language but there are some characters come in strange format such this:
ۇ  ۇ  ۆ  ۆ   ۈ  ۈ  ۇٴ   ۋچ

please i want to know why pdfbox can't read them correctly?

Comment: What do you mean by "can't read them"?  What output are your observing, and what did you expect?  Additionally, how are you using PDFBox when you see the unexpected output?

Comment: sample input in Arabic language : "يُرِيدُ اللهُ بِكًُمُ اليُسرَ ولا يُرِيدُ بِكُمُ العُسرَ"

Comment: the output come in this form: "ۇ ۇ ۆ ۆ ۈ ۈ ۇٴ ۋچ "
Expected output as render character by character from left to right:
رَ س ع ل ا  م ك ب.......

Comment: My code i am using in PDFBox:
  PDStream contents = page.getContents();
                if (contents != null) {
                    printer.processStream(page, page.findResources(),
                            page.getContents().getStream());
                }
then i use TextPosition to render file character by character
wait your reply!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48284888/writing-arabic-with-pdfbox-with-correct-characters-presentation-form-without-bei