# Writing Arabic with PDFBOX with correct characters presentation form without being separated

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I'm trying to generate a PDF that contains Arabic text using PDFBox Apache but the text is generated as separated characters because Apache parses given Arabic string to a sequence of general 'official' Unicode characters that is equivalent to the isolated form of Arabic characters.

Here is an example:
Target text to Write in PDF "Should be expected output in PDF File" -> جملة بالعربي
What I get in PDF File ->

[image: incorrect text]

I tried some methods but it's no use here are some of them:
1. Converting String to Stream of bits and trying to extract right values
2. Treating String a sequence of bytes with UTF-8 && UTF-16 and extracting values from them

There is some approach seems very promising to get the value "Unicode" of each character But it generate general "official Unicode" Here is what I mean

```
System.out.println( Integer.toHexString( (int)(new String("كلمة").charAt(1))) );
```

**output is 644 but fee0 was the expected output because this character is in middle from then I should get the middle Unicode fee0**

so what I want is some method that generates the correct Unicode not the just the official one

The very Left column in the first table in the following link represents the general Unicode
[Arabic Unicode Tables Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode)

Comment: Have you tried `codePointAt`?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov It is the same of output of charAt (644) and fee0 should be the expected output according to character position and form

Comment: [Here's something](https://github.com/w3c/alreq/wiki/Should-I-use-the-Arabic-Presentation-Forms-provided-in-Unicode%3F) to be said about char presentation forms. Apart from that, the only thing I could suggest then is to try using ICU library. Maybe that could help.

Comment: Thanks for your help .Have a new Day !

Comment: There was a mention on the pdfbox user mailing list (I think november or december 2017) of a person who had managed to do it.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Any chance to put hands on what that person did ?

Comment: It is here https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/pdfbox-users/201712.mbox/browser in the thread "Disconnected arabic characters".

Comment: It Worked ! Much Thanks. Can you put a detailed Answer or you want me to take care of that ? Here is the Line                                                                               Writer.showText(newStringBuilder(newArabicShaping(ArabicShaping.LETTERS_SHAPE).shape(target)).reverse().toString());                                                                                                                          .\n                                                                                                                   target is the String and Writer is PDPageContentStream

Comment: Thanks @M.Prokhorov for you too at first i thought that ICU library was for C++

Comment: @MinaGerges please do it.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr It's Done

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Can you tell me how to make PDPageContentStream object text flow direction right to left instead of LTR

Comment: There isn't AFAIK. I thought that the solution I pointed to made this all appear nicely?

Comment: yea solution was perfect but i want when i call showtext method text flows from right to left because i having hard time trying make Arabic lines start at the same vertical line

Comment: @TilmanHausherr is there any accurate way to measure string width ?

Comment: @MinaGerges *"The bounty expires in 6 days. Answers to this question are eligible for a +100 reputation bounty. Mina Gerges wants to reward an existing answer."* - I don't understand this bounty. The only answer is by yourself after all...

Comment: I was playing around the bounty system to understand how it works. so when i pressed the final button i expected a modal to appear saying "are you sure ?"
And Here We Are ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a code that works. Download a sample font, e.g. [trado.ttf](http://www.fontsaddict.com/font/traditional-arabic.html)

EDIT: I have since been using the [Amiri](https://www.amirifont.org/) font, which can be downloaded from the [`aliftype/amiri` Github](https://github.com/aliftype/amiri/releases/tag/1.000) repository.

Make sure the `pdfbox-app` and `icu4j` jar files are in your classpath.

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.ibm.icu.text.ArabicShaping;
import com.ibm.icu.text.ArabicShapingException;
import com.ibm.icu.text.Bidi;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException , ArabicShapingException
    {
    File f = new File("Amiri-Regular.ttf");
        PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
        PDPage Page = new PDPage();
        doc.addPage(Page);
        PDPageContentStream Writer = new PDPageContentStream(doc, Page);
        Writer.beginText();
        Writer.setFont(PDType0Font.load(doc, f), 20);
        Writer.newLineAtOffset(0, 700);
        String s ="جملة بالعربي لتجربة الكلاس اللذي يساعد علي وصل الحروف بشكل صحيح";
        Writer.showText(bidiReorder(s));
        Writer.endText();
        Writer.close();
        doc.save(new File("File_Test.pdf"));
        doc.close();
    }

    private static String bidiReorder(String text)
    {
        try {
        Bidi bidi = new Bidi((new ArabicShaping(ArabicShaping.LETTERS_SHAPE)).shape(text), 127);
            bidi.setReorderingMode(0);
            return bidi.writeReordered(2);
        }
        catch (ArabicShapingException ase3) {
        return text;
    }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 9):

#### Notice:

The sample code in this answer might be outdated please refer to [h q's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61147393/9098126) for the working sample code

---

At First I will thank [Tilman Hausherr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535646/tilman-hausherr) and [M.Prokhorov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7470253/m-prokhorov) for showing me the library that made writing Arabic possible using PDFBox Apache.

---

This Answer will be divided into two Sections:

1. Downloading the library and installing it
2. How to use the library

---

### Downloading the library and installing it

We are going to use [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) Library.
ICU stands for International Components for Unicode and it is a mature, widely used set of C/C++ and Java libraries providing Unicode and Globalization support for software applications. ICU is widely portable and gives applications the same results on all platforms and between C/C++ and Java software.

To download the Library go to the downloads page from [here](http://site.icu-project.org/download).
Choose the latest version of **ICU4J** as shown in the following image.
[image: Downloads Page]
You will be transferred to another page and you will find a box with direct links of the needed components .Go ahead and download three Files you will find the highlighted in next image.

1. icu4j-docs.jar
2. icu4j-src.jar
3. icu4j.jar

[image: Files]

The following explanation for creating and adding a library in **Netbeans IDE**

1. Navigate to the Toolbar and Click tools
2. Choose Libraries
3. At the bottom left you will find new Library button Create yours
4. Navigate to the library that you created in libraries list
5. Click it and add jar folders like that
6. Add icu4j.jar in class path
7. Add icu4j-src.jar in Sources
8. Add icu4j-docs.jar in Javadoc
9. View your opened projects from the very right
10. Expand the project that you want to use the library in
11. Right Click on the libraries folder and choose add library
12. Finally choose the library that you had just created.

Now you are ready to use the library just import what you want like that

```
import com.ibm.icu.What_You_Want_To_Import;
```

---

### How to use the library

With ArabicShaping Class and reversing the String  we can write a correct attached Arabic ***LINE***
Here is the Code **Notice the comments in the following code**

```
import com.ibm.icu.text.ArabicShaping;
import com.ibm.icu.text.ArabicShapingException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException , ArabicShapingException
{
        File f = new File("Arabic Font File of format.ttf");
        PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
        PDPage Page = new PDPage();
        doc.addPage(Page);
        PDPageContentStream Writer = new PDPageContentStream(doc, Page);
        Writer.beginText();
        Writer.setFont(PDType0Font.load(doc, f), 20);
        Writer.newLineAtOffset(0, 700);
        //The Trick in the next Line of Code But Here is some few Notes first  
        //We have to reverse the string because PDFBox is Writting from the left but Arabic is RTL Language  
        //The output will be perfect except every line will be justified to the left "It's not hard to resolve this"
        // So we have to write arabic string to pdf line by line..It will be like this
        String s ="جملة بالعربي لتجربة الكلاس اللذي يساعد علي وصل الحروف بشكل صحيح";
        Writer.showText(new StringBuilder(new ArabicShaping(reverseNumbersInString(ArabicShaping.LETTERS_SHAPE).shape(s))).reverse().toString());
        // Note the previous line of code throws ArabicShapingExcpetion 
        Writer.endText();
        Writer.close();
        doc.save(new File("File_Test.pdf"));
        doc.close();
    }
}
```

Here is the output

[image: Output]

I hope that I had gone over everything.

**Update** : After reversing make sure to reverse the numbers again in order to get the same proper number
Here is a couple of functions that could help

```
public static boolean isInt(String Input)
{
    try{Integer.parseInt(Input);return true;}
    catch(NumberFormatException e){return false;}
}
public static String reverseNumbersInString(String Input)
{
    char[] Separated = Input.toCharArray();int i = 0;
    String Result = "",Hold = "";
    for(;i<Separated.length;i++ )
    {
        if(isInt(Separated[i]+"") == true)
        {
            while(i < Separated.length && (isInt(Separated[i]+"") == true ||  Separated[i] == '.' ||  Separated[i] == '-'))
            {
                Hold += Separated[i];
                i++;
            }
            Result+=reverse(Hold);
            Hold="";
        }
        else{Result+=Separated[i];}
    }
    return Result;
}
```

Comment: for those who build with maven... the segment in the pom.xml would be `<dependency>
        <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
        <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
        <version>60.2</version>
    </dependency>`, to see the formatting see here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.icu/icu4j/60.2 .

Comment: And here is some explanation about maven and why you should use it           https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335351/what-does-maven-do-in-theory-and-in-practice-when-is-it-worth-to-use-it

Comment: If you want a library that does all this for you(bidi, shaping,reversing,etc) try OpenHTMLtoPDF. https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf

Comment: Works fine in case of new pdfs, when I am trying to update the pdf, it doesn't work. Here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55451551/unable-ot-save-arabic-words-in-a- pdf-pdfbox-java

Comment: i am still novice with library but what about using the content writer in the append mode ?